# Performance Testing for uploading file using SilkPerformer

Tags: struts, performance-testing, silk-performer

I am able to recorde the application that upload the file. During reply its running successfully but file is not getting uploaded. My question is

1) the whole file (Actual content of the file ) is getting displyed in the recorded script.

I have parameterized that.
 As the application is developed in struts 1.x so, there is struts taglib token generated which is dynamic so, i guses becoz of that my script is enable to upload the file

```
org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN := 9dd772f30792557daf87a3e46ad0e1ee
```

Please help me how to upload a file and test the performance of it.

Thanks